# How can I create a drawer / slider menu with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I create an a slider menu using Xamarin.Forms? Is it baked in or something custom?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You create a new class which contains all the definitions for both the Master - i.e. the *menu* - and the Detail - i.e. the *main* page. I know, it sounds back-to-front, but for example..

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace testXamForms
 {
   public class HomePage : MasterDetailPage
   {
   public HomePage()
   {
     // Set up the Master, i.e. the Menu

     Label header = new Label
     {
       Text = "MENU",
       Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize(20),
       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
     };
    // create an array of the Page names
     string[] myPageNames = {
       “Main”,
       “Page 2”,
       “Page 3”,
     };

     // Create ListView for the Master page.
     ListView listView = new ListView
     {
       ItemsSource = myPageNames,
     };

     // The Master page is actually the Menu page for us
    this.Master = new ContentPage
     {
       Title = "The Title is required.",
       Content = new StackLayout
       {
         Children = 
         {
           header, 
           listView
         },
       }
     };

     // Define a selected handler for the ListView contained in the Master (ie Menu) Page.

     listView.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
     {
       // Set the BindingContext of the detail page.
       this.Detail.BindingContext = args.SelectedItem;
        Console.WriteLine("The args.SelectedItem is
       {0}",args.SelectedItem);


     // This is where you would put your “go to one of the selected pages” 

       // Show the detail page.
       this.IsPresented = false;
     };
    // Set up the Detail, i.e the Home or Main page.
     Label myHomeHeader = new Label
     {
       Text = "Home Page",
       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
     };

     string[] homePageItems = { “Alpha”, “Beta”, “Gamma” };
     ListView myHomeView = new ListView {
       ItemsSource = homePageItems,
     };

     var myHomePage = new ContentPage();
     myHomePage.Content = new StackLayout
     {
       Children = 
       {
         myHomeHeader, 
         myHomeView
       } ,
     };
     this.Detail = myHomePage;
   }  
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is good, but for anyone that can't get it to work, you need to init myHomePage as a new ContentPage.  i.e. var myHomePage = new ContentPage();

Comment: I found an issue with masterdetail page.It minimize the application when hardware back button pressed.  It does not remember the navigation history. I have an app which uses masterdetail page to show menu in all page. The navigation is happened in two way in my app. one from the menu and second way from Dashboard. so if i navigate to another page, and then press "BACK" button, it closes the application. so any ideas how to overcome this problem?

Comment: You´re getting a downvote from me because of the formatting, what´s up with “Main”?

Comment: @animaonline it would be much more helpful for you to fix formatting problems than to downvote a valid answer.

Answer (score 16):

It is built in: `MasterDetailPage`. You'd set the `Detail` and `Master` properties of it to whatever kinds of Pages you'd like. I found [Hansleman.Forms](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms/blob/master/Hanselman.Portable/Views/RootPage.cs) to be quite enlightening.

Answer (score 13):

My minimum example (as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24700112/3419103)) is as follows:

```cs
public class App
{
    static MasterDetailPage MDPage;

    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        return MDPage = new MasterDetailPage {
            Master = new ContentPage {
                Title = "Master",
                BackgroundColor = Color.Silver,
                Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "menu.png" : null,
                Content = new StackLayout {
                    Padding = new Thickness(5, 50),
                    Children = { Link("A"), Link("B"), Link("C") }
                },
            },
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage {
                Title = "A",
                Content = new Label { Text = "A" }
            }),
        };
    }

    static Button Link(string name)
    {
        var button = new Button {
            Text = name,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
        };
        button.Clicked += delegate {
            MDPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage {
                Title = name,
                Content = new Label { Text = name }
            });
            MDPage.IsPresented = false;
        };
        return button;
    }
}
```

An example solution is hosted [on GitHub](https://github.com/perpetual-mobile/FormsMenuIcon).

On iOS the result looks like this (left: menu open, right: after clicking on "B"):

[image]
[image]

Note that you need to add the menu icon as a resource in your iOS project.

Comment: This solution is not hiding the Master view (in an iPad iOS 7.0.2). The MDPage.IsPresented= false statement is basically ignored. Xamarin Forms 1.2.3.6257.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for simple example of [MasterDetailPage](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage/) please have a look at my sample repo at [GitHub](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleMasterDetailTabbed). Very nice example is also presented [here](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-masterdetail-page-navigation-recipe/)

Answer (score 2):

Slideoverkit is a great plugin available for Xamarin Forms. There is a [github](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit) to see free samples and you could find documentation about it [here](http://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/).