# Show "Back to Menu" Button in iOS NavigationBar with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigationbar, master-detail

I'm trying to build a cross-platform app using C# and Xamarin.Forms. It contains a slide-out menu implemented in form of a `MasterDetailPage`. While on Android there is a button with the app icon in the top left corner, which toggles the slide-out page, there is no such navigation bar item on iOS.

I broke it down to the following minimum example derived from the Xamarin solution template "Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Shared)" and replacing the implementation of the `App`-class:

```cs
public class App
{
    static MasterDetailPage MDPage;

    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        return new NavigationPage(
            MDPage = new MasterDetailPage {
                Master = new ContentPage {
                    Title = "Master",
                    Content = new StackLayout {
                        Children = { Link("A"), Link("B"), Link("C") }
                    },
                },
                Detail = new ContentPage { Content = new Label { Text = "A" } },
            });
    }

    static Button Link(string name)
    {
        var button = new Button { Text = name };
        button.Clicked += delegate {
            MDPage.Detail = new ContentPage { Content = new Label { Text = name } };
            MDPage.IsPresented = false;
        };
        return button;
    }
}
```

The solution as well as resulting screenshots can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/perpetual-mobile/FormsMenuIcon).

My idea was to add such a "menu" or "back" button in the iOS-specific code modifying the `window.RootViewController.NavigationController.NavigationBar` within the `AppDelegate` class. But `window.RootViewController.NavigationController` is `null`.

Replacing the return type of `GetMainPage()` by `NavigationPage` instead of `Page` does not help.

I could add toolbar items via `MDPage.ToolbarItems.Add(...)`, but they appear in the top *right* corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The code basically needs two minor corrections:

1. Wrap all `DetailPage`s in a `NavigationPage`, but not the `MasterDetailPage` (see #1, #2 and #3 below).
2. Add an `Icon` to the `MasterPage` when on iOS (see #4 below). Don't forget to a the actual PNG(!) to the iOS resources.

The minimum working example is as follows:

```
public static class App
{
    static MasterDetailPage MDPage;

    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        return MDPage = new MasterDetailPage { // #1
            Master = new ContentPage {
                Title = "Master",
                Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "menu.png" : null, // #4
                Content = new StackLayout {
                    Children = { Link("A"), Link("B"), Link("C") }
                },
            },
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage { Content = new Label { Text = "A" } }), // #2
        };
    }

    static Button Link(string name)
    {
        var button = new Button { Text = name };
        button.Clicked += delegate {
            MDPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage { Content = new Label { Text = name } }); // #3
            MDPage.IsPresented = false;
        };
        return button;
    }
}
```

Comment: Originally I posted this solution as an update to my question. Just now I decided to move it into an explicit answer.

Comment: Is this App class is not same as the App class which extends the Application class ?

Comment: @Krrish: When I found this solution (shortly after posting the question), this was the way to extend the Application class. Due to a Xamarin.Forms update, this changed quite a bit. See [here](http://xforms-kickstarter.com/#a-slide-out-menu-using-a-master-detail-page) for a more up-to-date example of master-detail pages.

Comment: The icon was the key missing ingredient for me.  Poof, the back button shows up.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

Essentially, your `Detail` page needs to be wrapped in a `NavigationPage` for the back button to appear in iOS.

---

Here's an example of how I structure my apps.

**App.cs**

```
    public static INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    public static Page GetMainPage(IContainer container)
    {
        return new MainPage();
    }
```

**MainPage.cs**

```
public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        Title = "Some Title";
        var master = new MainMenu();
        var detail = new NavigationPage(new FirstPage());

        if (App.Navigation == null)
        {
            App.Navigation = detail.Navigation;
        }

        Master = master;
        Detail = detail;
    }
}
```

Now that you've done this, your Navigation Drawer will behave as expected, and so will your ActionBar.

When you want to navigate throughout the app, you use the statically defined `Navigation`

```
await App.Navigation.PushAsync(new FooPage());
// or
await App.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: Ok, doing the ```PushAsync``` on ```button.Clicked()``` opens a new detail page with a "Back" button, which - however - links back to the previous detail page, not the menu (a.k.a. master or MainMenu) as intended. Furthermore, the ```window.RootViewController.NavigationController``` is still ```null```, thus I can't modify the button this way.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a similar behavior as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVbcBdxIDwQ).

Comment: what's in that video is the default behavior if you do what I did above. Your `FirstPage` would be the page with that image on it. Note you also have to set the icon on the MainMenu (Master) page.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't achieve the desired behavior using your approach ([see App.cs at GitHub](https://github.com/perpetual-mobile/FormsMenuIcon/blob/master/App.cs)). The "Back" button always brings me back to ```"FirstPage"``` and not the ```MainMenu```.

Comment: That's how it's designed to work, are you trying to reveal the navigation menu?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want: A button to open the ```MainMenu``` - like it is in Android.

Comment: @Falko - Did you succeed in android when hardware "Back" button is pressed? I have problem as it minimize the application instead of going back.

Comment: @SoftSan: In ```MainActivity``` you can override ```OnBackPressed``` setting ```IsPresented=false``` if it is currently ```true```.

Comment: isPresented is for showing/hiding menu (if I don't misunderstood), I do it in my NavigateTo Method inside masterdetail page. IsPresented = false; You can visit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836805/xamarin-forms-master-detail-page-and-navigation-history-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right track, your NavigatePage needs to go on the Detail so

```
Detail = new ContentPage { Content = new Label { Text = "A" } }

and

MDPage.Detail = new ContentPage { Content = new Label { Text = name } };
```

would be

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage { Content = new Label { Text = "A" } })

and

MDPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage { Content = new Label { Text = name } });
```

Comment: This sounds very promising. (Since Android does not allow multiple navigation pages on screen at a time, I replaced ```return new NavigationPage(MDPage = ...)``` with ```return MDPage``` as well.)
But now I see an icon on Android and the title of the ```Master``` page on iOS. And ```window.RootViewController.NavigationController``` is still null, thus I don't see how to further control the appearance of the toolbar or the back button, respectively.