# Xamarin Form Master Detail Page not displaying

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the `Xamarin form with MasterDetailPage base class` But I am not able to get the master page .. Detail page is coming but `master` menu is not displaying .. Please check the code below. Do i need to specify any other method to call the `master` or anything wrong which i am doing in the below code

```
public class HomeView: MasterDetailPage
{
    public   HomeView()
    {
        Label header = new Label
        {    
            Text = "MENU",
            Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize(20),HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        Label header1 = new Label
        {
            Text = "MENU1",
            Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize(20),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        // create an array of the Page names
        string[] myPageNames = { "Main", "Page 2", "Page 3"};

        // Create ListView for the Master page.
        ListView listView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = myPageNames,
        };

        ListView listView1 = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = myPageNames,
        };


        this.Master = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = 
                {
                    header, 
                    listView
                }
            }
        };

        // Set up the Detail, i.e the Home or Main page.
        Label myHomeHeader = new Label
        {
            Text = "Home Page",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        string[] homePageItems = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };
        ListView myHomeView = new ListView 
        {
            ItemsSource = homePageItems,
        };

        this.Detail = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = 
                {
                    header1, 
                    listView1
                },
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to swipe to make the Master appear.  You can also assign a Title and Icon property to the Master ContentPage, this should display a button on the Detail that you can click to display the Master.

Comment: In addition to that: the title property is **required** for the Master's ContentPage.

Comment: I've posted a minimal working example for Xamarin.Forms master-detail pages [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24700112/3419103).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try the following Code:

```
public class HomeView: MasterDetailPage
{
    public   HomeView()
    {
        Label header = new Label
        {    
            Text = "MENU",
            Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize(20),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        Label header1 = new Label
        {
            Text = "MENU1",
            Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize(20),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        // create an array of the Page names
        string[] myPageNames = { "Main", "Page 2", "Page 3"};

        // Create ListView for the Master page.
        ListView listView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = myPageNames,
        };

        ListView listView1 = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = myPageNames,
        };

        this.Master = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = 
                {
                    header, 
                    listView
                }
                }
        };

        // Set up the Detail, i.e the Home or Main page.
        Label myHomeHeader = new Label
        {
            Text = "Home Page",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        string[] homePageItems = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };
        ListView myHomeView = new ListView 
        {
            ItemsSource = homePageItems,
        };

        this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = 
                {
                    header1, 
                    myHomeView
                },
            }
        });
    }
}
```