# Xamarin.Forms: Why is MasterDetailPage.IsPresentedChanged raised three times on Android?

Tags: android, events, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following minimal example of an app using Xamarin.Forms (version 1.2.3) and a `MasterDetailPage` (similar to: "[Show "Back to Menu" Button in iOS NavigationBar with Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24700112/3419103)"):

```py
public static class App
{
    static MasterDetailPage MDPage;

    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        MDPage = new MasterDetailPage {
            Master = new ContentPage {
                Title = "Master",
                Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "menu.png" : null,
                Content = new Button {
                    Text = "Open detail",
                    Command = new Command(o => {
                        MDPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage());
                        MDPage.IsPresented = false;
                    }),
                },
            },
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage()),
        };
        MDPage.IsPresentedChanged += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + MDPage.IsPresented);
        return MDPage;
    }
}
```

[(hosted on GitHub)](https://github.com/perpetual-mobile/FormsMenuIcon/tree/isPresentedChangedBug)

When opening or closing the `MasterPage` via **button click** on **Android**, the `IsPresentedChanged` event is triggered **three times** instead of once. According to the command line output the `IsPresented` property is either toggling as `True`-`False`-`True` or `False`-`True`-`False`, respectively.

Opening or closing using a swipe gesture or tapping on the `DetailPage` does work well. On iOS there is no problem at all.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is there a simple workaround to get a reliable event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the current version 1.4.0 of Xamarin.Forms the issue seems to be fixed. Opening the slide-out menu yields exactly one "True", closing it yields "False" - just as expected.