# Is possible to do sliding drawer in xamarin cross platform?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I am working in xamarin pcl project , I am trying to keep sliding drawer in my pcl project but i dont know how to do that .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a drawer / slider menu with Xamarin.Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964726/how-can-i-create-a-drawer-slider-menu-with-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Xamarin.Forms?

If not, i would advice to use a framework like MvvmCross (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross)
This would enable you to split the actual implementation of the drawer / hamburger menu into the different UI projects like iOS and Android(maybe WP8 too).

Since those platforms all behave differently, for example Android uses Fragments which are replaced inside the activity containing your navigation drawer, you should use a custom presenter to determine where you want the specific platform to navigate to. You can find more information on that topic here: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/presenter-roundup.html