# `Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception while using Navigation Drawer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm trying to create a `navigation drawer` using `Syncfusion SfNavigationDrawer`, but I get the following exception on android simulator.

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setClipToOutline' signature='(Z)V' in class Lcom/xamarin/forms/platform/android/FormsViewGroup;

This is my code:

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{       
    public MainPage()
    {
        SfNavigationDrawer nav = new SfNavigationDrawer();

        StackLayout mainStack = new StackLayout();
        mainStack.Opacity = 1;
        mainStack.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        mainStack.HeightRequest = 500;
        mainStack.BackgroundColor = Color.White;

        ObservableCollection<String> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        list.Add("Home");


        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.WidthRequest = 200;
        listView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        listView.ItemsSource = list;
        mainStack.Children.Add(listView);

        nav.DrawerContentView = mainStack;


        StackLayout headerLayout = new StackLayout();
        headerLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;

        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("user.png");
        headerLayout.Children.Add(image);

        Label header = new Label();
        headerLayout.Children.Add(header);
        nav.DrawerHeaderView = headerLayout;



        Button imageButton = new Button();
        imageButton.WidthRequest = 50;

        Label homeLabel = new Label();
        homeLabel.Text = "Home";
        homeLabel.FontSize = 15;
        homeLabel.TextColor = Color.White;
        homeLabel.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        homeLabel.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

        StackLayout headerFrame = new StackLayout();
        headerFrame.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        headerFrame.Children.Add(imageButton);
        headerFrame.Children.Add(homeLabel);

        Label mainLabel = new Label();
        mainLabel.Text = "Lorem...";

        StackLayout ContentFrame = new StackLayout();
        ContentFrame.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        ContentFrame.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        ContentFrame.Children.Add(headerFrame);
        ContentFrame.Children.Add(mainLabel);
        nav.ContentView = ContentFrame;

        nav.Position = Position.Left;
        nav.Transition = Transition.SlideOnTop;

        this.Content = nav;

    }
}
```

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms 2.3.0.49`, and `Syncfusion ES 14.2.0.26`. And I should note updating `Xamarin` and `Android build-tools` didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Here is the answer from the Syncfusion support team:
The reported crash "No method with name setClipOutline" has been fixed in our latest Essential Studio Volume 2 Service Pack 2, 2016 (Version 14.2.0.32) and is available for download under the following link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/125638/essential-studio-2016-volume-2-service-pack-release-v14-2-0-32-available-for-download

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug in the lib. See the latest post in their forum [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/125385/error-when-deploying-application-on-android-device-no-method-with-name-39setcliptooutline39-signature). Try to use alternate solutions from [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43181/side-drawer-menu-in-xamarin-forms-for-ios-and-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964726/how-can-i-create-a-drawer-slider-menu-with-xamarin-forms).

In summarization from links:

https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-masterdetail-page-navigation-recipe/

https://varunrathore.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/xamarin-forms-navigation-drawer/

http://xforms-kickstarter.com/#a-slide-out-menu-using-a-master-detail-page

http://blog.falafel.com/xamarin-creating-a-sliding-tray/

Hope it helps!