# Coding a Navigation Drawer Menu (Slider Menu). (Master Page Detail)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to build a Slider menu I´m using this docu coming from official Xamarin. 
[MasterPageDetail](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage/)

Quite odd, it´s not working. VS2015 intellense recognized me MasterDetailPage (my class is inheriting from it), but when I´m trying to launch the app, next error appears:

**The type or namespace name 'MasterPageDetail' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

What it happens? Do you know of any simply working demo?
I´m using this question as reference, but I´m not getting it works...
[Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964726/how-can-i-create-a-drawer-slider-menu-with-xamarin-forms)

Some answer uses MasterPageDetail, another one implemented the solution in app (class) and I need to do it in a ContentPage

Thanks mates.

EDITED: I´m using Xamarin.Forms and I imported it and I don´t have any class called like this (MasterPageDetail)... Quite odd, it sounds like a stupid thing but I can´t see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

Finally I clean all project and started a code from zero using the next example (adding just MasterPageItem.cs, piece of cake):

[Working MasterDetailDemo](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/)

I improved the demo by my own, creating a Master Page Detail where Master´s items bind specific generic page, it will be fill with its own attributes whose depends of id passed to the page´s constructor.

[Github Slider Menu improved demo](https://github.com/EliasMerabet/Net/tree/master/Xamarin/Cross/NavigationDrawer)

Hoping it helps...

Answer (score 0):

MasterDetailPage  is class from Xamarin.Forms if you have class with the same name then it may be a conflict.

Here are some useful links:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage/

You can also download my Example from my Github:

https://github.com/15mgm15/XamarinForms-MasterDetailPage-Recipe

Comment: Hi @Mario Galván. Nope, I´m using Xamarin.Forms and I imported it and I don´t have any class called like this... Quite odd, it sounds like a stupid thing but I can´t see it.

Answer (score 0):

- There's a simple way to create a `MasterDetailPage` using XAML, first of all you need to create a page which will contains the `MasterDetailPage` and a `SecondPage` which will contains a `DetailPage`, by doing this, you need to change your hierarchy of this page to `MasterDetailPage`, and finally load a `SecondPage` inside of `MasterDetailPage`.
- In your project Create a New Page - `MenuPage` and change the Page Type ContentPage to `MasterDetailPage`

  ```
  <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       BackgroundColor="White"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="YourProject.MenuPage">
  </MasterDetailPage>
  ```
- Then go to your `MenuPage.cs` and change the hierarchy to MasterDetailPage too.

  ```
  public partial class MenuPage : MasterDetailPage
  {
     public ChatPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
  }
  ```
- Go back to your XAML page - `MenuPage` and add this :

  ```
     <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="YourProjectName.MenuPage">

  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage  Title="Menu">
     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <!--Here goes your Menu Items-->
       <Button Text="MyFirstButton"/>
       <Button Text="MySecondButton"/>
       <Button Text="MyThirdButton"/>
     </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <local:SecondPage/>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
  </MasterDetailPage>
  ```
- And finally you need to add a reference to your `DetailPage`

  ```
     <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="YourProjectName.MenuPage"
       <!-- Add this line to refer your DetailPage, `SecondPage`-->
       <!-- put your namespace and repeat in assembly -->
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectName;assembly=YourProjectName">
     </MasterDetailPage>
  ```

I hope its helps you!